# Group by and aggregate when colums change over time in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, aggregate, clickhouse

Assume I have following table in Clickhouse:

```
f_datetime, f_user, f_tile
2021-07-08 07:00:00, x, a
2021-07-08 08:30:00, x, a
2021-07-08 08:45:00, x, a

2021-07-08 09:00:00, x, b
2021-07-08 11:00:00, x, b

2021-07-08 12:00:00, x, a
2021-07-08 15:00:00, x, a

2021-07-08 16:00:00, x, b
2021-07-08 20:00:00, x, b
```

I want an aggregate query to get following results:

```
f_user, f_tile, f_duration
x, a, 105
x, b, 120
x, a, 180
x, b, 240
```

I want to Grouping and calculate duration until f_tile, f_user  changes in an ordered table by f_datetime.

Is there any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163259/how-to-sum-the-values-of-a-column-for-several-rows

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  For this version, the simplest solution is probably the difference of row numbers:

```
select f_user, t_tile,
       min(f_datetime), max(f_datetime),
       date_diff('minute', min(f_datetime), max(f_datetime)) as f_duration
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by f_user order by f_datetime) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by f_user, f_tile order by f_datetime) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by f_user, f_tile, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The next datetime value in your table is the lowest value for this user which is >= the datetime of the current row.

```sql
SELECT t.f_user, t.f_title,
(SELECT MIN(t1.f_datetime) 
    FROM Yourtable t1 
    WHERE t1.f_datetime >= t.f_datetime AND t1.f_user = t.f_user AND t1.f_tile = t.f_tile) - t.f_datetime
FROM Yourtable t
```

Instead of substract these values you can apply your DIFF function.

Answer (score 1):

As you want calculations over each continuous `f_tile` segment (per `f_user`, I'm guessing), here's one approach, using window functions:

- data: The initial table.
- cte2: Find edge of each continuous `f_tile` run per `f_user`
- cte3: Calculate a group (`grp`) indicator for each run for aggregation
- cte4: Calculate the duration for each `f_tile` run

```
WITH cte2 AS (  -- Find edges of each f_tile run for each f_user by datetime
        SELECT t.*
             , CASE WHEN LAG(f_tile) OVER (PARTITION BY f_user ORDER BY f_datetime) = f_tile THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS edge
          FROM data AS t
     )
   , cte3 AS (  -- Assign a group (grp) indicator for each run for aggregation
        SELECT t.*, SUM(edge) OVER (PARTITION BY f_user ORDER BY f_datetime) AS grp
          FROM cte2 AS t
     )
   , cte4 AS (
        SELECT f_user, f_tile, grp
             , MIN(f_datetime) AS start
             , DATE_DIFF('minute', MAX(f_datetime), MIN(f_datetime)) AS duration
          FROM cte3 AS t
         GROUP BY f_user, f_tile, grp
     )
SELECT f_user, f_tile, duration
  FROM cte4
 ORDER BY start
;
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+----------+
| f_user | f_tile | duration |
+--------+--------+----------+
| x      | a      |      105 |
| x      | b      |      120 |
| x      | a      |      180 |
| x      | b      |      240 |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Note: I don't have a clickhouse instance to test.  Adjust as needed.  I've tested the equivalent with another engine.